# Error loading Groovy config file from JAR

Tags: groovy, jar

I have an application that is running on compiled Groovy code in a jar.

The groovy code is all being loaded/executed correctly, however, I have a step that attempts to load a groovy-config file from the root of the JAR, but it is failing.

The code below is from a groovy class that is being run from the JAR, and here it attempts to load the groovy config file `config.props` from the root of the jar:

```
URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("config.props")
logger.info( url.toString() )
if(!url)throw new IllegalArgumentException("'$resource' not found ")
GroovyScriptEngine gse = new GroovyScriptEngine( url )
...
gse.run(url.file, binding)
```

When I run the above I get the following error:

```
Message: Cannot open URL: jar:file:/usr/local/libs/test-all.jar!/config.props
```

Does anyone have any idea how to load a file from a root of a jar?  I have temporarily set the permissions to 777 and have checked that the file exists/spelling correct.

Comment: You've tried the absolute path (with a leading slash) yeah? `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/config.props")`

Comment: If so, my second guess would be to unpack the jar somewhere and check the `config.props` file is actually where you think it is

Comment: @tim_yates - thanks, Yes, I have tried this. Actually, the error message is it cannot open the URL. If i pass in a junk name in the first line then I get a different error (I get an error saying file does not exist). So the problem seems to be not that it can't find the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - I think I have resolved this.

It looks like the error was in

```
gse.run(url.file, binding)
```

the `url.file` passed the full absolute path including `file:` protocol to the gse - I changed this to just "`config.props`" and it seemed to have got past this (there is another error now, but seems to be further on).

Comment: Thank you for your question and answer--I had the exact same problem.  I was using "url.file.text" to get the text and it turned out that what I needed was "url.text" instead.  You should probably go ahead and accept your answer.